# How to create this visualization / name of this circle trending visualization?

Tags: powerbi, visualization

I recently came across a visualization in PowerBI, but cannot find it in the AppSource.  Does anyone know how to create this visualization?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According both with [The Data Visualisation Catalogue](https://datavizcatalogue.com/methods/spiral_plot.html) and [DataVizProject](https://datavizproject.com/data-type/spiral-histogram/), this type of visualization is either a Spiral Plot or a Spiral Histogram, as you can see in the image below:

[image: Solar Wind Speed Metrics]

But probably, the example you have provided (created by [Net Solutions](https://www.netsolutions.com/casestudy-ecom-dashboard)) adds to the thing sort of a "Ring Plot" with bubbles, so, in essence, we are talking about mixing two kinds of visualization.

As they are a private company charging for its services, my bet is they have done the work in Power BI using a custom visual not publicly available. Nevertheless, you can use [this template](https://bl.ocks.org/arpitnarechania/027e163073864ef2ac4ceb5c2c0bf616) done in **D3.js** as starting point, and then, [render it](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104381354) in your dashboard.

Comment: This is really interesting!  I will give it a shot.  Thanks!